KDE Konsole : is there a documentation for the layout / profile JSON files?
My aim is to use Konsole in the same way I use Terminator: Loading a specific layout with a set of split terminals and their geometry PLUS the profiles for these terminals and eventually a command that should be executed (for instance ssh -t remote "emacs foo.bar ; bash -l").
I am already aware that you can save a layout from the menu. Yet the layout does only include the geometry, not the profiles that were loaded when the layout was saved.
Searching the internet hasn't brought up even a hint, besides the basic feature that layouts exist. I have sought here in the Stack Exchange network, on plain Google, on Reddit and in several KDE forums, including the official ones), to no avail.
What I need is just to load a specific profile with the layout.
I am not sure if it can be of any help, but htere is an example layout for a window split into 4 (the geometry is irrelevant):
    {
    "Orientation": "Horizontal",
    "Widgets": [
        {
            "Orientation": "Vertical",
            "Widgets": [
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                },
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SessionRestoreId": 0
        }
    ]
}

Can anybody offer some help here?

this is a question and answer site ... it is not a chat forum ... Can anybody offer some help here? has a yes answer ... it does not ask for anything more ... furthermore, it is not a question about the problem ... please ask a question about the problem instead
